# Python: Python version in Mac

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, zsh

Issue: When I typed `python -V`, It gives me python 2.7.16 which is Apple's inbuilt system instead of python3.7

Initially, I followed the below steps and installed the latest python version which is 3.9 and it worked fine perfectly

```
brew install python
```

Since I use `zsh` by default, I put the following into the .zshrc file:

```
$ echo "alias python=/usr/local/bin/python3" >> ~/.zshrc
```

But my project required a python3.7 version so I have uninstalled it using `brew uninstall python@3.9`  and then installed `brew install python@3.7`

Also ran `echo "alias python=/usr/local/bin/python3" >> ~/.zshrc`

But now when try to run  `python -V` it points to the Python2.7 version not Python 3.7 version

Also check where it is installed

```
% which pip3
/usr/local/opt/python@3.7/bin/pip3
% which python
/usr/bin/python
% which python3                                                                                                                                                         
/usr/local/opt/python@3.7/bin/python3
```

Need help to fix this issue.

Comment: Did you `source ~/.zshrc` after you made the edits?

Comment: I realized that i have updated the path in ~/.zshrc  to `/usr/local/opt/python@3.7/bin/python3`

Comment: In the future you might want to look at e.g. `pyenv` for maintaining multiple installations of Python.

Comment: you really should be using virtual environments, either venv-based or conda work

Comment: Don't define this alias. Put `/usr/local/bin` earlier in your path (if it isn't already ahead of `/usr/bin/`), or create a virtual environment for your project based on your Python-3.7 installation.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to cleanly manage multiple versions of python on one machine is using the conda package manager,which comes with the Anaconda distribution. You can create a separate conda environment for each Python version you want to use by running:

```
conda create --name mypy37env python=3.7
conda activate mypy37env
```

For details on how to create and manage conda environments, take a look at [the docs](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html)